# Best way to run application on linux from windows and collecting all results

Tags: python, linux, windows, ftp, paramiko

I am looking for the best way for running an application remotely on linux box from  windows using python. The application may take long time to finish and all the results are files (mainly txt and cvs).
If you suggest paramiko, please give me an example how to collect the results and transfer it to windows after finishing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a web service on some framework, like tornado, cherrypy etc. You can make something like API to do remote execution, and you can make static file serving to get files.

You also can use [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), saltstack

You can use libraty like [remotely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/remotely)

So please provide more information how do you want to solve your task.

Comment: What exactly I want is like this:
1-For example I want to execute a code on linux machine
foo -i input_file (where foo is exe in linux box I can access via ssh)
This code may take 5 hours to execute and will result in 
file1 file2 file3 file4 in a directory.
2-I want to be able to execute foo from my windows machine and get the pid of this specific job. 
3-I want to add in addition a job monitor for this job to check if finished or not. 
4-The last thing is to collect the resulting files and send them back to the windows machine automatically after the job is finished

Comment: I think you want really custom task and you should write it yourself. I see it like this: 

1.  You have web service. You can send your task by http to this service. Answer will be some ID.
2.  Your client application get this ID and shows to you
3.  server application can start your task in separate thread or process and can monitor activity. It you ask server for status for ID server will check and return status. 
4.  after task is finished, you can download by result files through http by task ID.